# numpy applying aggregated information across a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

i have a list of agent's "health" in a 2D array:

```
health=[[0.5,0.8],[0.1,0.5],[0.5,0.7]]
```

and a set of actions( one per agent):

```
actions=[[0,1],[2,0],[1,1]]
```

(possible actions = {0,1,2}

depending on their actions, their health gets increased, according to payoff matrix:

```
payoff[agent_row][action]=
  [[0,0.2,0.5],
  [0,1,0.6],
  [0,0.2,0.4]]
```

calculating their new health is done by:

```
health=[[0.5,0.8],[0.1,0.5],[0.5,0.7]]
actions=[[0,1],[2,0],[1,1]]
payoff= \
    [[0,0.2,0.5], \
    [0,1,0.6], \
    [0,0.2,0.4]]
for r,h in enumerate(health):
    for i,_ in enumerate(h):
        health[r][i]+=payoff[r][actions[r][i]]

print health
```

How can I use numpy to speed things up?

Bonus points given for a solution which works in a reasonably stable version of pypy

Comment: EDIT: code should be working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy you can use integer arrays directly to index other arrays. For example `A[[0, 1, 2], [11, 12, 13]]` will return an array with 3 elements which are `A[0, 11], A[1, 12] and A[2, 13]`. Here is how you can apply this concept to your problem.

```
import numpy as np

health = np.array([[0.5, 0.8], [0.1, 0.5], [0.5, 0.7]])
actions = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 0], [1, 1]])
payoff = np.array([[0, 0.2, 0.5],
                   [0, 1, 0.6],
                   [0, 0.2, 0.4]])

r, c = np.indices(health.shape)
health += payoff[r, actions]
```

This is called advanced indexing, [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) is a good reference for it.

Comment: oook... I knew it was going to be simple, but not this simple.

Comment: It's going to take ma a while to digest though. Anyone has a numpy document reference for this functionality?

Comment: Sorry, the link I posted isn't the one I meant to post. I thought there was a good article that introduced advanced (sometimes also called fancy) indexing. I hope someone else knows what I'm talking about and can post the link.